# How to create a custom non-rectangular GroupBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, user-controls

Is it possible to to make a `GroupBox` that looks like the image below?

If it is not possible with the native controls are there any free, custom controls that might support this?

[image]

Comment: Haha. No. Change the layout of your controls. Otherwise, you'll be drawing it yourself with `ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D`. People create controls that they think will actually be useful; this isn't.

Comment: @HPT: 1. this is  strange control, so it's extremely unlikely anyone has ever even considered it.  2. By asking "how can I make X", we don't know anything about your skills. Have you create custom controls before? Or do you need us hold your hand during installing Visual Studio?  If oyu are interested in helpful answers, post a helpful question.

Comment: @peterchen: I dont think SO is for holding hand during some process, I just looked for an idea to make developmenting or implementing faster,  Yes, I know how to write custom controls.

Comment: Why the votes to close this question?  Seems like a valid resuest to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no control like the image which you made, I have a *non intelligent* solution, but might match your requirement,

Create a `UserControl` and put inside it two `GroupBox` controls, then you'll have a line between them, you can hide it by add a panel above it without `None` for `BorderStyle`.

Then you'll have this user control:

[image]

I know it's not as intelligent as you want, but might it's easier than drawing one from scratch and loose the theme.

You can also create a title property to reflect the vertical groupbox as a title of the user control

```
public string Title
{
    get { return groupBox1.Text; }
    set { groupBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'm immediately intrigued by answers which suggest that their solution is "non intelligent". I just don't know if that intrigue is a *good* thing.

Comment: Well it may solved the problem but I wouldn't go for this approach I would draw a custom control. And since you are my friend I won't vote down :P

Answer (score 6):

No, such a control does not exist in the framework. You could make one yourself by creating a control, that inherits GroupBox.

Comment: @HPT: It's a perfectly reasonable answer IMHO. He suggested you a valid solution, you can't pretend people even implement things for you or find something that likely doesn't exist...

Comment: @HPT, you do ask "How to make a GroupBox like this ?", and I answered that. You are not asking a specific question about the implementation, so I can't answer that. Also, I know for a fact that it doesn't exist in the framework, so I wanted to include that information for you. As for the rest of your question - you can Google it easily. I didn't find anything really usable.

Comment: I googled before I ask this question. SO is a full of professionals who know more than google sometimes!

Comment: how can I create X? you could create X yourself by creating it! very useful answer!

Comment: @HPT: I'm seriously tempted to vote down your question and flag your comments. You're so irritating! SO _is not_ full of professionals. Granted, there are professionals within our midst but many of us here are regular guys contributing our knowledge. HPT gave you a good answer. You either **take it or leave it**!

Comment: @Alex: You mean driis gave you a good answer. At any rate, it's hardly unusual for people to ask unclear and ambiguous questions, then berate those who try to help them anyway. That's why I've started to post more comments than answers recently, because too many people expect you to read their mind and get mad when you can't.

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to find a control like this.  You can make one yourself, the Control.Region property lets you create a non-rectangular control.  You'll have to draw the outline and the title yourself, do so in the OnPaintBackground override.

But, realistically this control isn't going to be very interesting as a re-usable control that might be of use in other forms or projects.  Keep in mind that it only has to *look* like a groupbox to the user.  Since you have to write the drawing code yourself anyway, just do so in the form's Paint event.  If you really need a box because of radiobuttons then use a Panel instead.  Do keep in the Form.AutoScaleMode property in mind, you can't hard-code the line positions.

Comment: is it possible to set the `GroupBox.Region` property to a `GraphicsPath` and draw the border with `ControlPaint`?

Comment: Not really.  GraphicsPath.Widen() goes the wrong way, you can't shrink it.